# change the Drools web desginer UI by introducing new buttons/features

Tags: web, designer, drools, jbpm

Is it possible to change the Drools web desginer UI by introducing new buttons/features? I want to be able to add the risk management functionality to the time and cost process simulation? How can I make changes to the editor? I am a novice in web development.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the Process Designer from the jBPM? 
Yes you can the Process Designer is an open source project you can find the source code in github